# How can one make the output current of an OTA flow to the load?

Tags: circuit-design, analog, integrated-circuit

I would like to use the following circuit as an OTA and deliver an output current to the load.

[image]

However, I found that most of the current from M4 flows into the drain of M2. Very little current flows into the load.

How can I make most of the current deliver to the load?

Comment: What is an OTA?

Comment: What's your load exactly? Just a resistor or something more complicated? What's the voltage at the input of your load with zero input current?

Comment: @ScottSeidman operational transconductance amplifier.

Comment: OTA = Operational Transconductance Amplifier. Acronyms  like this need to be defined (Google lists 65 possibilities).

Comment: @JonathanS. The load is a resistor, at kohm range. Vdd = 1 V.  INP = 0.9 V,  INN = 0.85 V.

Comment: If Vdd is 1 volt, and the load is 1K, the load current will be at most 1 mA.

Comment: @PeterBennett In simulation, the current delivered to the load is only 1 uA. Most of the current flows into the M2.

Comment: What happens if you would make the \$V_{GS}\$ of M2 so low that it cannot conduct, then the current from M4 has no choice other than to flow into the load. How can the \$V_{GS}\$ of M2 be influenced? I see this input INN, could that be used? I suggest that you try to understand **how** this circuit works, how the voltages and currents are related.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie But actually I can't set Vgs of M2 to a voltage below its threshold voltage. That is because INN is supposed to be properly biased. My purpose is to produce a current to the load. Such current should be proportional to the voltage difference between INP and INN.

Comment: What's the sizing of those N-FETs? Are they all identical in W/L ratio?

Comment: @JonathanS.  NMOS (W: 10 um, L 180 nn); PMOS (W: 20 um; L 360 nn)

Answer (score 1):

This circuit will work if you dimension it correctly.

You said that only about 1µA flowed into your load resistor. This is expected as your current mirror M5/M6 biases your OTA with only 10µA. The amplifier can't magically generate more output current than its bias current. If you want an output current of 1mA, you'll have to bias it appropriately, i.e. with 10mA. Furthermore, M1 to M4 have to be wide enough to generate enough gain so you can get the full output current in the first place.

Additionally, the "OUT" node between M2 and M4 can't go all the way to VSS or VDD. If the voltage at this point gets too high or too low, one of the FETs will enter its ohmic region and the circuit won't function as a current source anymore. This means that your load can't return to VSS, it should ideally return to a voltage halfway between VDD and INN.

Comment: I set the width of M5 a few hundred times larger than M6. So the bias current should be in a few hundred uA range. However the majority of the current still flows into M2.

Comment: The majority of the current **should** flow into M2, otherwise the OTA will become quite non-linear. The bias current is only one problem with the circuit, though. You still have to adjust the width of M1-M4 (wider = more gain) and also make the load current not return to ground. M1-M4 should be at least as wide as M5, possibly a lot wider.

Comment: But an OTA is supposed to deliver an output current. If the majority of the current flows into M2, that means there is little current flowing to the load. In this case, doesn't the OTA fail to deliver output current?

Comment: The current delivered by this OTA is the difference of M1's and M2's drain current. It's a differential amplifier. The difference of these currents gets created at the M2-M4 node. Without M2, the circuit wouldn't even be an amplifier because it'd always supply its maximum output current.

Comment: Then do mean the load should be connected from the drain of M2 to the drain of M1 instead of from the drain of M2 to the ground?

Comment: No, it should be connected from the drains of M2/M4 to a reference voltage that's not ground. You'll have to figure out the exact voltage based on your requirements for output current range / input voltage range.